# How to print the first 10 and last 10 observations in SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics

I'm trying to find a way to only print the first 10 and last 10 observations of my SAS dataset. Is there a way I could do this?

I tried `proc print data = ia.usage; where Obs < 10 & Obs > 80;run;`
But the command still prints out all 90 observations. Any idea on how to do this easily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Getting the first 10 is easy:

```
/*First 10 obs*/
proc print data = ia.usage(obs = 10); run;
```

Getting the last 10 is a bit harder, but this can be done using a view:

```
/*Last 10 obs*/
data last10 /view = last10;
  startobs = nobs - 9;
  set ia.usage nobs = nobs firstobs = startobs;
  drop startobs;
run;
proc print data = last10; run;
```

If you want both in the same proc print, you can create two views and combine them into another view, then print it:

```
data first10 /view = first10;
  set ia.usage(obs = 10);
run;

data first10_last10 /view = first10_last10;
  set first10 last10;
run;

proc print data = first10_last10; run;
```

The above method should be very fast, even for large datasets, but it assumes that your intial dataset is not a view, as it relies on knowing the number of rows (nobs) in the dataset. If you have a view then you will need to read through the whole dataset to find out the number of rows, then read it again, throwing away everything except the first and last 10 rows. This will be much slower. E.g.

```
data first10_last10 /view = first10_last10;
  do nobs = 1 by 1 until(eof);
    set ia.usage(drop = _all_) end = eof; /*We only want the row count, so drop all vars on this pass to save a bit of time*/
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 to nobs;
    set ia.usage;
    if _n_ <= 10 or _n_ >= nobs - 9 then output;
  end;
run;

proc print data = first10_last10;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a single view:

```
data want/view=want;
  set ia.usage nobs=__nobs;
  if _n_ le 10 or _n_ gt __nobs-10;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: This may be slow for large datasets as it involves reading the whole dataset rather than just the first / last 10 rows.

Comment: yes, agreed, the approach you submitted is more efficient